# Get the list of item from list that contains other list

Tags: string, linq, list

I have a list of string.
I want to get the list items that matches the other list.
i.e, if First List values contains the value from other string return all the values.

```
 List<string> fileNameToMatch = new List<string> { "nsevar", "cat", "elm", "nse isin", "l6scripsv2eq" };
 List<string> fileToMatch = new List<string> { "fevnsevarc", "gfcatgf","ratstts","mymatch"};
```

The second list contains the values the are present in first list.
So return all values.

The output should be "fevnsevarc" and "gfcatgf" in list.

Can we use some link to get the names from the fileToMatch  which contain data from fileNameToMatch

Comment: Have you written some code to do this that isn't working, or are you asking someone to write it for you?

Comment: I want the code Sir..If possible i am stuck

Comment: This is the scenario.And how to get the expected ouptput is what i need.Dont knwo how to write prope linq for this

Comment: _"The output should be "fevnsevarc" and "gfcatgf""_ Why?? _"The second list contains the values the are present in first list."_ No!

Comment: Becaus the string values from second list contains "nsevar" and "cat" which are in the first list.Its like fevnsevarc.contains(nsevar). But here i have a list to match instead of single value.

Comment: I mean second list contain value "fevnsevarc" and this contains "nsevar" which is present in the first list.

Comment: Great to see negative marking for my doubts..I think they should not be asked rather..

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal: It was not clear what you have asked because _first list contains_ means that the first list contains the same item, not part of the item in the second list. You could also have chosen better sample data to show effort and to make the problem more descriptive. You should always try to show a minimum effort, that makes it easier to understand the requirement, it also avoids the impression of "Give code!".  Last, the title has nothing to do with the question. That's the reason for the downvote. Apart from that, there are countless duplicates on SO.

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal Your question comes across as though you haven't tried to solve it yourself. Check [ask] for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: I tried this thing but did not work.Anyways i will try to make the questions more clearer next time.I googled a lot and tried contains query but could not write properly.Extremely sorry in case this question bothered you people.i Have not asked this question for sake of marks but i was stuck in problem. :(

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal A good starting point for future questions is to post the code you've tried already, and be specific about how it doesn't work: does it give you the wrong results - what results are they? Does it throw an exception - what does the exception say? That way, everyone involved learns something, rather than Stack Overflow just being a database of code snippets written by people for others.

Comment: @  shambulator Definitely i will keep that thing in mind.Thanks for the suggestion and help..

Comment: @ shambulator I just saw the heading it was from the last question that i wanted to ask around 3days ago.BUt could not post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var res = fileToMatch
    .Where(f => fileNameToMatch.Any(fn => f.IndexOf(fn) >= 0))
    .ToList();
```

This is nearly self-explanatory: you are looking for all files `f` in `fileToMatch` such that a file name `fn` exists in the `fileNameToMatch` where `f` is contained anywhere in `fn` as a substring.

**EDIT :** (in response to a comment) To get the `fn` along with `f`, add a `Select`, and use an anonymous type, like this:

```
var res = fileToMatch
    .Where(f => fileNameToMatch.Any(fn => f.IndexOf(fn) >= 0))
    .Select(f => new {
        File = f
    ,   Name = fileNameToMatch.First(fn => f.IndexOf(fn) >= 0)
    })
    .ToList();
foreach (var match in res) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", match.File, match.Name);
}
```

Comment: I modified the code in this way and it worked.'files.Where(f => fileNameToMatch.Any(fn => f.IndexOf(fn) >= 0)).ToList();'

Comment: Can we get the fn values also from the above function.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight  its giving me the first element from the list always as Name.Here i am always getting "nsevar" as name

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply sir.I have been working on this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var result = fileToMatch.Where(x => fileNameToMatch.Any(y => x.Contains(y)));
```

Comment: It works.Can i get the value of "y" also along with the result.?

Comment: There could be multiple items that were found. So it's not that simple as getting the value of y.

Comment: But i need to identify the file type based on "y".Is there any other work around like appending some values at the end or any other thing we can do.